# Django add new object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have `project_detail` page. Inside that page I have link which will redirect user to another page where user can add new members to current project. As you see from the code below I created form with 2 fields *user* and *role*. How to associate new members with current project? I tried next code but I have error when try to save new member. Here below you can see full trackback also. It seems to me system dont know in what project must be new member. I tested with 2 databases the sqlite and MS SQL SERVER. The result was same in both of them. How to fix this error.

**models.py**:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ***FIELDS***
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership',)

class Membership (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES,)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class ProjectMembersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        exclude = ('project',)
```

**views.py**:

```
def project_detail(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id, status='public')
    return render(request, 'project/project_detail.html', {'project': project})


def add_project_member(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectMembersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_member = form.save()
            new_member.save()
            return render(request, 'project/project_detail.html', {'project': project, 'new_member': new_member})
    else:
        form = ProjectMembersForm()
    return render(request, 'project/project_members.html', {'project': project, 'form': form})
```

**urls.py**:

```
url(r'^projects/(?P<project_id>\d+)/$', project_detail, name='project_detail'),

url(r'^projects/(?P<project_id>\d+)/members/add/$', add_project_member, name='add_project_member'),
```

link in 'project_detail' page looks like this:

`<a href="{% url 'project:add_project_member' project_id=project.id %}">OPEN</a>`

**Trackback**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\views.py", line 70, in add_project_member
    new_member = form.save()
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 453, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1045, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1054, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 539, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ('23000', '[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]�� ������� �������� �������� NULL � ������� "project_id", ������� "RMS.dbo.project_membership"; � ������� ��������� �������� NULL. ������ � INSERT. (515) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is ought due to `project` field which is a required one inside the `Membership` model but is excluded inside `ProjectMembersForm` (thus, it fails when `new_member = form.save()` is executed).

You should change your `add_project_member` view to this:

```
def add_project_member(request, project_id):
    # get project
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # bound form with POST data (without the 'project' one)
        form = ProjectMembersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # form does not contain the "project" field. Its excluded!
            new_member = form.save(commit=False)
            # add project to member, manually
            new_member.project = project
            # save member to db
            new_member.save()
            ...
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: One more question, after successfully adding the member I want redirect user to `project_detail` page again but the link has disappeared. How do you think why this behavior happens?

Comment: Have you tried instead of returning `render(...)` to do: `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project_detail', kwargs={'project_id': project.id}))`. Note, that with this redirect, the `new_member` will not get passed in the context.

Comment: Well I tried this but it raise error: `Reverse for 'project_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'project_id': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` I'm a little confused. What do you think about that?

Comment: Ah, found it! Forgot the namesapce. Come on! Try this `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project:project_detail', kwargs={'project_id': project.id}))`

Comment: I found in other post of stackoverflow that we miss namesapce also. But anyway it dont redirect to `project_detail` page after successfull adding new member. It still show `add_project_member` page. What do you think about that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137848/discussion-between-nik-m-and-nurzhan-nogerbek).